# Cold storage for existing database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL database that will not be updated anymore. However, it should be infrequently accessible only for SELECT queries for the next two years. Is there a some cost effective way to keep this database?

It would be great to move the database in some cold storage but I'm not sure if this option exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the Azure SQL database as a serverless database.
It would remain paused during inactive time
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql&tabs=general-purpose

It would only be active when you try to query again